# Xamarin Forms Customized Camera for iOS and Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm pretty new to Xamarin Forms and C# in general, and need som hints on the best way to create an app for iOS and Android. I want to use the Camera to take pictures / videos and later on send them with email or something else, since I want customized controls on the camera, I'm guessing the stock camera won't be an option? Which gets us to Renderers, which is the best approach to this? Preferably in a MVVM way. I just want the camera and a few customized buttons on it.

Do I make on renderer for the different buttons objects and one for the camera, the buttons I'll do as extensions of the Button class, but what about the camera?

/Oliver

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create a page renderer and put your camera/buttons native in each platform.
2. Create a view renderer for the camera and add your view in any page of Forms, so you can put your buttons or anything you like in forms.

Comment: would you care to elaborate that a bit more, I would like to go on the second choice with view renderer, but am still not totally sure how to do this properly. /Oliver